# How can I secure my payment with remote work client?

Tags: contracts, payment-terms, payments, remote

I am planning to work with a remote client. The only way to communicate with my client is by a phone call or message.

In order to secure my payment term, I am thinking of creating a contract which will be renewed monthly. Is the contract sufficient or do I need to get some other proof before starting my work with the client?

Comment: Hi. I have the same question. Do you think that this one is helpful for you [How to get paid and figure out if I want to keep this client](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/479/15099)?

Comment: Really not certain what you are asking. No one knows if someone *will* pay. And if they intend not to a contract *rarely* changes that. Get payment up front.. that's really the only way to ensure you are paid.

Comment: @Scott I am getting 50% in advance 50% after completion

Comment: I advise you to set contract only on upwork or on freelancer.com. Upwork also allow you to set contract even if the client does not have upwork account. This will save you horrible head ache if the client wouldn't pay you coz the platform admins will be your lawyer in case of. This is not an advertisement of x or y, I am talking from my several years experience.

Comment: I agree with you but it was not my intention. I worked on several freelance paltforms and from my experience the only 2 ways to protect your hard work is to work only on well known freelance platforms such as freelancer.com and upwork.

Answer (score 1):

This is the part of freelancing that always makes me question my life choices. lol.

Past experience has taught me to always write up a contract. I don't do any work until the contract is signed and I receive 1/2 the amount I'm charging for the work. They don't receive the finished product (or it doesn't go live) until I've been paid in full.  But my work tends to be a by-the-project basis with an additional hourly charge for additional work done.

If you're doing hourly work only, I'd outline the payment terms in the contract, and send them monthly invoices. If they fall behind in payments stop working until the pay you.

There's really no way to guarantee you'll be paid, but writing out a contract and sending out invoices does help. There are a ton of free resources out there to help you with freelance paperwork. One of my favorites is https://www.freelancersunion.org/

hope this helps!

Comment: I am getting 50% in advance but another problem is I need to push all the changes to git repository. My question is can I take legal actions if my payments is not made.

Comment: Yeah, of course, you can. But you have to be ready to pay all the fees that go along with doing that. The laws where you live will have an effect on the outcome. Make sure you have a good contract and keep track of all your invoices, emails, and call-log if you make phone calls, as it helps your argument if you do end up having to go to court.

Answer (score 1):

> In order to secure my payment term, I am thinking of creating a
>   contract which will be renewed monthly. Is the contract sufficient or
>   do I need to get some other proof before starting my work with the
>   client?

A contract is a legal document. You should never perform any work without having a contract signed by all parties.

A contract doesn't guarantee that a client will pay you, but it gives you legal recourse if they don't.

> Can I take legal actions if my payments is not made?

Yes, you can. Again, there's no guarantee that you'll receive payment or win a legal judgment against a client, but you certainly can take legal action.

Additionally, if you don't have it already, make sure that you have Professional Liability Insurance and General Liability Insurance, or their equivalents. These provide you financial protection should a client sue you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to guarantee payment is to be paid IN ADVANCE. I'm currently awaiting payment from a client for whom I performed work remotely; we had a contract, but I'm getting one excuse after another re. actually getting paid despite how pleased he was about the work I did. I got burned by a different client last year; I had a contract w/ him, too (I ended up opening a collections case against him).

The lesson for me (and you) is get paid in advance. This is standard procedure when doing search engine marketing (SEM) / paid-per-click (PPC) work, and I think we need to apply it for other types of work as well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think using freelancering platform is the best way to secure the payment. Like Upwork and Toptal.

Comment: For Upwork the major thing is commission. It is 20% for each payment.

Comment: @RajendranNadar They charge you based on lifetime earnings with each client: 20% for the first $500 you bill your client. 10% for total billings between $500.01 and $10,000. 5% for total billings over $10,000.