# Is it unacceptable or not wise to email clients during the weekend?

Tags: freelance-websites, communication, working-from-home, time-management, design

This Exchange question here: [Staying in contact with clients when I have a different sleep-wake rhythm (being a night owl or living in a different time zone)](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/195) deals with the subject quite well, but it is more focused towards a specific problem. This question is quite generic. That being said, if this is mainly down to opinion or too broad I do apologise.

Normal business hours are Monday through to Friday. Usually 9am until 6pm (or very similar). Is it considered then bad practice to email clients during the weekend; large organisations within the creative, digital industry do not work weekends. The weekend is a time of rest.

Should all business communication be kept to normal business hours? Would you say you significantly increase the risk of your client taking a dislike to you if you email them at the weekend?

Answer (score 6):

Here's my *opinion* and practice....

I **never** respond or contact clients during *any* time I want to myself, ever.

That is to say.. I don't respond to or contact clients before 9am, after 5pm, on weekends or on holidays - even *if* I happen to be working. If I get an email from a client at 6pm Friday night.. I do not respond until 9 am Monday at the earliest. I don't answer my phone after about 5:15 pm unless the caller ID tells me it's a personal call.

The reason for this is primarily to kind of train clients in my availability. The *moment* a response is seen during traditional "off-hours" a client will customarily start to *expect* you to be available during those periods. Responding on weekends causes this to happen *very rapidly*. They'll start contacting you every weekend.

What it all boils down to ... if I want time to myself, it's up to me to enforce and live by it. The more lax I get with my available client time, the more it will continually dwindle down to nothing. And I have no intention of being "on call" for my clients all the time.

Note: I offer **no** services whatsoever which would *ever* constitute an "emergency" during off-hours with the possible exception of time zone differences. However, if time zones mean I'm contacted, it would be *before* the start of my work day... so I respond at 9am then.